# array_push won't give an array, prints out integer value

Tags: php, arrays

I'm doing a very simple php program with array_push, but it isn't working according to the documentation. Every time i try to print the value of the final array, it gives me an integer. Could someone please help me with this?

Here's my code:

```
<?php
    $preArray = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8');
    $val = 10;
    $array = array_push($preArray, $val);

    print_r($array);
?>
```

This is what it outputs:

```
9
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`array_push()` returns the new number of elements in the array. So if you're not interested in the number of elements in the array then just use:

```
array_push($preArray, $val);
```

The variable $preArray will contain the value pushed into it.

```
print_r($preArray);
```

Comment: most of us would just do: `$preArray[]=$val`

Comment: @Dagon - not me - i push values into arrays using array_push() :))